# Preencher automaticamento os valores da Listbox como selecionados.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quando os dados vão para a ListBox queria que fossem logo selecionados:
Não sei porque não funcionada.

```
 itensListBoxCatequizandos.append('<option value="' + obj.val + '"> ' + obj.name + '</option>').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. solucionei o problema:

```
 $.each(myCheckboxes, function (i, obj) {
            itensListBoxCatequizandos.append('<option value="' + obj.val + '"> ' + obj.name + '</option>');    
            $("select option[value=" + obj.val + "]").attr("selected", true);           
        });
```